# On integrability of a distribution in $\mathbb R^3.$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, integrable-systems

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $P,Q,R$ be smooth real-valued maps on $M=\mathbb R^{3}$ with $P^{2}+Q^{2}+R^{2} \neq 0.$ Let, $E(a)$ denote the orthogonal complement of the subspace $S$ in $T_a(M)$ spanned by the smooth vector field $(PD_x + QD_y +RD_z)(a).$

Show $E$ is a smooth distribution in $M$ and is integrable iff
$P(D_zQ -D_yR) + Q(D_xR -D_zP) + R(D_yP -D_xQ)=0$

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ Here, $E$ is a rank-$2$ distribution and let $V_1(a) = \sum_{i=1}^3 {V_1}^i(a) D_{e_i}|_{a}$ and $V_2(a)= \sum_{j=1}^3 {V_2}^j(a) D_{e_j}|_{a}$ are bases of $S.$

So, $P{V_1}^1 + Q{V_1}^2 +R{V_1}^3 =0.$
$P{V_2}^1 + Q{V_2}^2 +R{V_2}^3 =0.$

Then, I think ${V_1}^i$ and ${V_2}^j$ will be smooth (also we can create basis of $S$ like $(Q,-P,0)$ and $(0,R,-Q)$ , so $E$ is smooth) .

Now, by Frobenius' theorem, involutive $<=>$ integrable .

Applying the formula of $[V_1,V_2]$ (Lee, Smooth manifolds Proposition 8.26, pg 186) , I can't properly bring the expression in the question .

A small hint is warmly appreciated, thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you familiar with the Frobenius theorem in terms of differential forms? The problem essentially gives a global $1$-form $\omega$ which generates the distribution, so involutivity is equivalent to $d\omega=0$.

Comment: No, I am only a beginner in Diff Geo ,it'll be better if you give hints not in terms of diff forms .

Comment: There are two things you have to consider: 1) what if Q=0? (your basis would not be a basis anymore in this case) 
2) $[V_1,V_2]\subset E \ \Leftrightarrow \ \langle [V_1,V_2],PD_x+QD_y+RD_z\rangle=0$ where $\langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the induced inner product on the tangent space.